# When can I access an objects variable using object.variable?

Tags: java, variables, inner-classes, instance-variables

Probably a simple question I should by now. I'm writing some code for a class and I have 1 class that I have 3 instance variables of

class LruC {

int counter
int RAM_address
boolean valid_invalid

constructor takes no parameters

**methods**

private class Page {

```
private Page () {
  count = 0;
  invalid_valid = false;
}
```

}

Then I have the nested class Page inside of LruC. In some of my methods that are inside the LruC class I'm creating instances of the Page object, then I'm trying to access their variables by just doing Page.count or Page.invalid_valid and I'm getting compile time errors saying it doesn't recognize the variables.

When is it feasible to access an objects variable by just doing object.variable_name? Does it have something to do with the fact that the count and invalid_valid variables are not inside the Page class? I thought since it was nested it would have access to all those variables?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of providing pseudo-code, it would really help if you'd provide a [mcve], with appropriate formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I could not quite understand how the relationship between your two classes. But it seems like a problem with scope of your variables (protected, private or public). One class can access public variables of another class. If you haven't but any statement before your variable the compiler assumes it is private, therefore you can not access from another class. You need to put public before your variable or create a Get method which returns the variable.

Note: this is a very simple answer so and I am assuming that all your classes are in separate files and none of your classes extends or implements each other.